# Django FileResponse Content-Disposition header not working for filename

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I use the Content-Disposition header because the stored name of the files is different from the name they are served. But header not working in all files correctly, i'm directly passing filename to header. Filenames contains non-ASCII characters.

Here is the download view i'm using:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def download_streamer(request, **kwargs):
    dlo = DownloadLink.objects.get(token=kwargs['token'])
    if dlo.is_expired:
        return Response({'link_expired': 'Download link expired, try again'},
                        status=status.HTTP_410_GONE)
    else:
        mimetype, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(dlo.file_cache.stored_at)
        f_response = FileResponse(open(dlo.file_cache.stored_at, 'rb'), content_type=mimetype)
        f_response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={dlo.file_cache.origin.name}'
        f_response['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'Content-Disposition'
        FileActivity.objects.create(subject=dlo.file_cache.origin, action='GET', user=dlo.owner)
        return f_response
```

Here is the valid response header which i want (file name not containing non-ASCII chars)

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename=jinekolojik aciller.ppt
```

But some files gives this headers (original filename: türkiyede sağlık politikaları.pdf)

```
content-disposition: =?utf-8?q?attachment=3B_filename=3Dt=C3=BCrkiyede_sa=C4=9Fl=C4=B1k_politikalar=C4=B1=2Epdf?=
```

Comment: I'm getting the same in my code, have you get a solution for this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution for this.

I noticed that when name contains any non legal character response's 'Content Disposition' guess messed up and the browser cannot get the file name out of it.

solution for me was

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

@api_view(['GET'])
def download_streamer(request, **kwargs):
    dlo = DownloadLink.objects.get(token=kwargs['token'])
    if dlo.is_expired:
        return Response({'link_expired': 'Download link expired, try again'},
                        status=status.HTTP_410_GONE)
    else:
        mimetype, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(dlo.file_cache.stored_at)
        f_response = FileResponse(open(dlo.file_cache.stored_at, 'rb'), content_type=mimetype)
        f_response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={slugify(dlo.file_cache.origin.name)}'
        f_response['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'Content-Disposition'
        FileActivity.objects.create(subject=dlo.file_cache.origin, action='GET', user=dlo.owner)
        return f_response
```

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Desposition header is set automatically, the file name is also encrypted automatically. You only need to set 'Content-Disposition' in the 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers', that`s all. A living example:

test file: 'Снимок экрана от 2024-01-21 17-59-41.png'

Back:

```
    file = UserFiles.objects.get(user=params[0], name=params[1])
    response = FileResponse(file.file, as_attachment=True, filename=params[1])
    response['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'Content-Disposition'
    return response
```

Front:

```
console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Disposition'))
```

Browser console output: "attachment; filename*=utf-8''%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%202024-01-21%2017-59-41.png"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).